# Trying to show "..." after 110 characters using css

Tags: html, less, whitespace

Hi I am having hard to show html and css to show "..." after 110 characters. Thing is width is fixed and height (number of lines) can be multiple as shown picture.[image]

Here is the existing html and css code:

```
<div class="course-preview-body">
  <p class="course-preview-header">{{competency.title}}</p>
  <p class="product-preview-description">{{{competency.overview.statement.text}}}</p>
</div>
```

```
.course-preview-body {
    padding: 20px 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100px;
    .course-preview-header {
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .product-preview-description {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
```

Help me to fix the give code to resolve the issue..

Comment: That's not CSS. That LESS or SASS or some other CSS preprocessor. Please either add the appropriate tag(s) or post the compiled CSS

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use a templating engine. If that's the case then the easiest way would be to cap the length already in there.

```
<p class="product-preview-description">{{competency.overview.statement.text.substring(0, 110) + "..."}}</p>
```

This is also good for sending less over-the-wire.

If you want to only show the ellipses if the text is longer than 110 characters you can use a ternary operator.

```js
const longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erectus samir nulla quam armanus aleatus quantum yemir artnatus iacta cum laude est";
const ellipses = longString.length > 110 ? "..." : "";
const shortString = longString.substring(0, 110) + ellipses;

console.log("Long:", longString);
console.log("Short:", shortString);
```

Comment: there will be an ellipsis even if the text does not contain 110 letters

Comment: `<p class="product-preview-description">{{competency.overview.statement.text.substring(0, 110) + (competency.overview.statement.text.length > 110 ? "..." : "")}}</p>` should fix this. This looks a bit messy, so I would suggest adding a new property to `competency.overview.statement` called `shortText` that essentially does the same and you render that instead.

Answer (score 0):

**In CSS, you don't have the possibility to display the "..." character after the 110th character.**

However, the following options are available:

1.) **You can determine on which line the "..." should appear.** (maybe optional with css)

```css
.product-preview-description {
  overflow: hidden; /* if want ..., then text too long */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* if want ..., then text too long */
  display: -webkit-box; /* if want ..., in last row */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* as many lines as you need */
}
```

Or...
2.) You can add the "..." character before the overflow of a text without line breaks at the end of a box, if the text doesn't fit the full width of the box.

```css
.course-preview-header {
  max-width: 100%; /* 100% or any value */
  overflow: hidden; /* if want ..., then text too long */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* if you want ..., then text too long */
  white-space: nowrap; /* if you need one line, disable row break */
}
```

---

Fixed 110 characters is not a great solution since the number of lines in the description could vary, which is not ideal if you are displaying multiple descriptions in a grid-like layout. It's better to consistently limit the number of displayed lines to a predefined value.

**If you still insist on using 110 characters, you can truncate the text using Java, Python, PHP, JavaScript, or any other language you are using.**

Example with JavaScript:

```js
// ~ 200 charachters
const text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet risus velit. Sed euismod lacus nec mauris pellentesque, sed blandit dui congue. Donec blandit, nisi ut tempor interdum, ex mauris mattis odio, vel commodo elit nulla eu enim. Vivamus sit amet risus vel felis semper vulputate. Sed finibus dolor sapien, nec ullamcorper metus dignissim ac. Aliquam sed dapibus neque, id posuere eros. Nullam dignissim lorem id neque accumsan convallis. Etiam molestie erat felis, quis venenatis risus blandit eu. Sed eget eros sit amet augue rutrum dapibus. Sed eleifend lectus non metus consectetur bibendum. Praesent ut risus nec mauris lacinia porttitor. Maecenas ut pulvinar ante. Praesent vel magna eget nisl placerat vehicula.";

// 110 charachters from text
console.log(text.slice(0, 110));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the output of some js variables (looks like Vue.js).
Css cannot count letters unless you put each one in a tag:

```css
span:nth-child(11):after {
    content: '...';
}

span:nth-child(n+12) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- after 11 goes ... -->
<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span>d</span><span>e</span><span>f</span><span>g</span><span>h</span><span>i</span><span>j</span><span>k</span><span>l</span><span>m</span><span>n</span><span>o</span><span>p</span>
```

Therefore, it will be simpler like this (аf you don't create a variable for `competency.overview.statement.text`):

```js
{{
competency.overview.statement.text.length > 110 ?
competency.overview.statement.text.slice(0, 110) + '...' : 
competency.overview.statement.text
}}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it hack and dirty, but _inappropriate_ use in the context of the question.